# How can I light only one LED at a time depending on voltage input?

Tags: voltage, led

I have an input voltage in the range of 0-4. When it is v>1 a blue LED will turn on, when v>2 a red LED will turn on but the blue will be turned off, when v>3 the green LED will be turned on but the others will be turned off.

I'm thinking of using multiple comparators to check for each scenario but it feels like that could become quite messy. Any suggestions? Preferably without a microcontroller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like you have an approach (even if your question is lacking physical units, and it makes a practical difference whether you detect 1kV, 1 V or 1 mV, leave alone 1 µV). So, what's the question you're asking? "Any suggestions?" is not *actually* a question.

Comment: What if the microcontroller is the simplest and cheapest way to do it? Do you still prefer doing it without a microcontroller? If you only need to detect if voltage is below or above some level, and there are only 3 levels, you get 3 bits out and some logic to decode to three LEDs.

Comment: Four window comparators are sufficient, each in one of the following ranges:0-0.95V, 1-1.95V, 2-2.95V, 3-4V

Comment: You don't need window comparators for this.

Comment: @Justme: No logic needed.  Just the comparators.

Comment: @BenVoigt Justme's point was not that you need logic per se, but that it may be the simplest/cheapest way to do this. It's a relevant point given that the question gave no reasons for the aversion to microcontrollers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Without logic you would need more than 3 comparators to define in which range you are in and which LEDs to keep on or off. And then they can't have exact thresholds, there might be 1 millivolt between two ranges where both LEDs or no LEDs are turned on.

Comment: @InBedded16: I suppose if the suggestion is ADC + digital comparison then yes, that could reduce part count.  But there wouldn't be external logic then (because the micro is perfectly capable of doing that logic in software).  So I assumed Justme meant "three bits out of analog comparators and use microcontroller to perform the logic", which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Justme: Did you even read my answer before making such claims?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I did.

Answer (score 4):

You have three thresholds, so clearly you <strike>need</strike><sup>1</sup> will use three comparators.  If the comparator output drive strength is enough current for the LED, you need no other active components.

Simply connect the green LED (and current limiting resistor) between the 3.0V comparator output and ground.  The red LED (and resistor) between the 2.0V and 3.0V comparator outputs.  And the blue LED (and resistor) between the 1.0V and 2.0V comparator outputs.

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually possible with two, if you use [some clever feed-forward from one comparator output to control the reference voltage for a second](https://aldenbradford.com/two_bit_adc.html).  But that would make the LED control more complex.

Comment: @vir: No, they won't.  The LEDs placed between two comparator outputs will light only when there's a voltage difference, meaning one comparator is high and one low.

Comment: @BenVoigt Comparators generally don't have push pull outputs. Can you draw a schematic how would this be achieved with just 3 comparators, LEDs and resistors?

Comment: @Justme Comparators with push-pull outputs are just as common as those with open-drain.

Comment: @BenVoigt They could be. I can't name even one. The ones I know have open-drain outputs. But I guess you can always add push-pull buffers after a comparator anyway to achieve the same, so yes, with the assumption of having push-pull outputs one way or another, this will work.

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/amplifier-ics/analog-comparators/?output%20type=Push-Pull

Comment: Clever. I rescind my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a LED dot/bar display driver. It has the comparators and current sinks all built in already.